# How can I extract a unique 5-digit number from a string using a VBA Regex in Excel?

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I have series of strings of the following nature in Excel

```
/item/index/offid/77203/uSasdf/ASFDFAS/catId/401/subCat/709
```

Each string contains multiple numbers separated by backslashes. One of these numbers, however, is a unique 5 digit number, and each string will contain only once such 5 digit identifier.

I'd like my VB based macro to pull out that 5 digit number from each string.

The unique IDs I'm looking for can be either 5 or 6 characters. It is always the first number in the string and I know that the unique ID has terminated once I reach the preceding backslash.

Comment: So, in your example, you want to extract `77203`?

Comment: @armstrhb Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most regex, a five-digit number is just: `\d{5}`

But perhaps you can have several five-digit numbers, as in '`/itemindex/12345/12345/77203/', and you want to capture the ones that are guaranteed to be unique, in this case`77203`.

In that case, you need a lookahead, as in:

```
^(?=.*(\d{5})(?!.*(\1)))
```

The lookahead asserts that the number captured to Group 1 is not found later (backreference `(\1)` to Group 1).

In VBScript, for the first regex, you can pull the overall Match with this:

```
Dim myRegExp, FoundMatch
Set myRegExp = New RegExp
myRegExp.Pattern = "\d{5}"
FoundMatch = myRegExp.Test(SubjectString)
```

For the second regex, where we retrieve the match from Group 1, you need something like this:

```
Dim myRegExp, Group1, myMatches, myMatch As Match
Dim myRegExp As RegExp
Set myRegExp = New RegExp
myRegExp.Pattern = "^(?=.*(\d{5})(?!.*(\1)))"
Set myMatches = myRegExp.Execute(SubjectString)
If myMatches.Count >= 1 Then
    Set myMatch = myMatches(0)
    If myMatch.SubMatches.Count >= 1 Then
        Group1 = myMatch.SubMatches(1-1)
    Else
        Group1 = ""
    End If
Else
    Group1 = ""
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just edited the question because I realized the problem was more complicated than I initially realized. Basically, the unique ID is sometimes 5 digits long, and sometimes 7 digits long.